# OnClick runs once only

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple piece of code for toggling the contents visibility of textareas, the first expands the textarea to display the entire contents and the second returns it to its previous size with scroll bars displayed. Both buttons work fine the first time through but after that do nothing, no errors as far as I can tell, any ideas what I need to do here to keep both buttons working after their initial run

```
<button
onclick='document.getElementById("input0").style.overflow="visible";
        document.getElementById("kpi1").style.overflow="visible";
        document.getElementById("m_kpi1").style.overflow="visible";
        document.getElementById("g_kpi1").style.overflow="visible"'
></button>

<button 
onclick='document.getElementById("input0").style.overflowY="scroll";
        document.getElementById("kpi1").style.overflowY="scroll";
        document.getElementById("m_kpi1").style.overflowY="scroll";
        document.getElementById("g_kpi1").style.overflowY="scroll"'
></button>
```

Comment: The first is setting `overflow`, the second is `overflowY`.

Answer (score 1):

because both button are setting different properties and and once it set there is no use to reset it, if you want revert first button setting on second button click than it will work.

try:

```
<button
onclick='document.getElementById("input0").style.overflow="visible";
        document.getElementById("kpi1").style.overflow="visible";
        document.getElementById("m_kpi1").style.overflow="visible";
        document.getElementById("g_kpi1").style.overflow="visible"'
></button>

<button 
onclick='document.getElementById("input0").style.overflow="scroll";
        document.getElementById("kpi1").style.overflow="scroll";
        document.getElementById("m_kpi1").style.overflow="scroll";
        document.getElementById("g_kpi1").style.overflow="scroll"'
></button>
```

one suggestion pult javascript code in function and call it in onclick.

```
function setOverflow(value){
  document.getElementById("input0").style.overflow=value;
  document.getElementById("kpi1").style.overflow=value;
  document.getElementById("m_kpi1").style.overflow=value;
  document.getElementById("g_kpi1").style.overflow=value;
}
```

and html:

```
<button onclick='setOverflow("scroll")'>scroll</button>
<button onclick='setOverflow("visible")'>visible</button>
```